# SQLCmd with connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Can I Pass connection string via SQLcmd?

I want to change application Name and failover partner (for mirroring) by connection string when use sqlcmd.

Now. When I use sqlcmd, application name of my connection set `SQLcmd` in sys.sysprocesses result.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know - perhaps consider using osql, with the -D parameter and set up an ODBC connection, which would get you failover partner support at least.